# How to find text of all child nodes

Tags: java, xpath, webdriver, htmlunit

I am using webdriver to crawl websites for looking for links decorated with a magic constant, except that the text may be formatted:

```
<a href="blah" ..><span blah>magic</span></a>
```

and to many levels

```
<a href="blah" ..><span blah>A <span blah><b>magic</b></span> evening</span></a>
```

I don't know whether or not it is formatted, or if it is, how many levels deep it goes, as I'm searching through arbitrary sites.

My code looks something like this:

```
List<WebDriver> links = driver.getElements(By.tagName("a"));
   for (WebElement link : links) {
       List<WebElement> children = link.getElements(By.tagName("*"));
           for (WebElement child : children) {             
              if (myPattern.matcher(child.getText()).matches()) {
                 System.out.println("found match!");
              }
           }
    }
```

But this fails to find the match.

Any ideas on how to determine if there is a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to get the text content, then from there is pretty straight forward

```
String html = "<a href=\"blah\"><span blah>...<b>magic</b>...</span></a>"
String string = Jsoup.parse(html).text(); //A magic evening
if(string.contains("magic")){ //you can optimize to have word match, e.g. not "magical"
    //it's a match
}
```

**Edit:**

I didn't use WebDriver/Selenium for a long time, but I've seen something like this which looks like it might have the same effect

```
String innerText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerText", element);
```

Comment: OK, I will try this. But I was hoping for something a little lighter weight, using the normal webdriver APIs.

Comment: the issue here is that if the link contains the magic string, I want to click on it, and the href target could be javascript. But I will checkout jsoup.

Comment: Didn't use WebDriver/Selenium for a long time, but I've seen something like this which looks it might have the same effect, but this is not tested and a wild guess: `String innerText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return
arguments[0].innerText", element);`

Comment: A variant of this worked. On firefox, textContent does the trick, but it doesn't work on htmlunit. There, I used innerHtml and then processed the html to grab the text content. If you promote your comment to an answer, I can select it.

Answer (score 2):

**In case you can use XPath, one useful XPath expression is**:

```
//a[span[.//text()[. = 'magic']]]
```

This selects all `a` in the XML document that have a `span` child that has a text-node descendant, whose string value is the string `"magic"`.

Comment: right, but I don't know if there is or is not a span child, or how many span children there are. Again, I'm testing arbitrary sites. I want to recursively look for all children and obtain their text.

Comment: Then what the "magic" word has to do with all this? You definitely need to edit your question and provide a better source XML and a better explanation.

Comment: The question is fine, it just needs to be read from start to finish. I say that I don't know whether there will be a span or not, and I even give examples of the types of formatting I expect to encounter. Your proposed answer fails on the examples provided in the question.

Comment: @rsj: Then you need to explain what is the meaning of "decorated with a magic constant". If we want a useful solution, we better not use prose in the definition of the problem.

Comment: @rsj: If you can explain precisely which element you want to be selected, then I will likely be able to give a single XPath expression that selects only this element.